# Implement two SELECT DISTINCT in one query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sap-erp

I have this query that works perfectly, it brings me 6 fields, 5 from a table A and 1 field from another table B, in an INNER JOIN.

```
rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT "
                           + "MSEG.ZEILE,MSEG.MATNR,MAKT.MAKTX,MSEG.WERKS,MSEG.LGORT "
                           + "FROM SAPVEP.MSEG "
                           + "INNER JOIN SAPVEP.MAKT "
                           + "ON MSEG.MATNR = MAKT.MATNR "
                           + "WHERE MSEG.MBLNR = '"+ Data +"' AND MSEG.MANDT = 300 "
                           + "ORDER BY MSEG.ZEILE ");
```

This generates this query and it works perfectly for me, because I want to fill a JTable with that data.

```
0001
TR00004016
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 11/2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
150.000

0002
TR00004014
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 11/2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
500.000

0003
TR00004014
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 11/2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
100.000
```

The problem comes at the moment of adding to the query another field that is in a C table, for this I did the following:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT "
"MSEG.ZEILE,MSEG.MATNR,MAKT.MAKTX,MSEG.WERKS,MSEG.LGORT,CNMSEG.MENGE "
                               + "FROM SAPVEP.MSEG "
                               + "INNER JOIN SAPVEP.MAKT "
                               + "ON MSEG.MATNR = MAKT.MATNR "
               add this line-> + "INNER JOIN SAPVEP.CNMSEG "
               add this line-> + "ON MSEG.MBLNR = CNMSEG.MBLNR "
                               + "WHERE MSEG.MBLNR = '"+ Data +"' AND MSEG.MANDT = 300 "
                               + "ORDER BY MSEG.ZEILE ");
```

**IT BRINGS ME 3 TIMES THE SAME RECORD!**
I tried to use GROUP BY, but it didn't work.
I am sure that a DISTINCT could solve the problem, but I don't know where to put it since I am calling it in the first line!

I need help. Please

```
0001
TR00004016
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 11/2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
150.000

0001
TR00004016
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 11/2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
222.000

0001
TR00004016
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 11/2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
304.000

0002
TR00004018
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
150.000

0002
TR00004018
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
222.000

0002
TR00004018
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
304.000

0003
TR00004020
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 21/2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
150.000

0003
TR00004020
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 21/2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
222.000

0003
TR00004020
TUB RANURADA 795ROJA ELECTROS 21/2"SCH10
1000
IMPO
304.000
```

Comment: This depends on how you want to choose which of the three values of `CNMSEG.MENGE` to include in your output.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem  IN CNMSEG there is the same key of ZEILE... CNMSEG.ZEILE where would you put it as the output in the query?

Comment: *IT BRINGS ME 3 TIMES THE SAME RECORD!* it is not the same. The last column is different. So which of the 3 values for this column do you want in the results?

Comment: @forpas ZEILE, CNMSEG.ZEILE

Comment: `MBLNR` and `ZEILE` are key fields in `MSEG`, so you do not need any `DISTINCT`: the output you want to achieve is caused by wrong query design. You need to include `MANDT` field in join condition for both the tables (`MAKT` and `MSEG`) and filter out only the language you need from material texts: `where ... and makt.langu = 'E'`

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that the join condition should be `ON MSEG.MBLNR = CNMSEG.MBLNR  AND MSEG.ZEILE = CNMSEG.ZEILE`.  But without knowing your table structure, who can say?

Comment: Also use [preparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and placeholders instead of concatenation. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: @astentx Could you answer the question in more detail please?

Answer (score 1):

CNMSEG is a view of MKPF (header table for MSEG) and MSEG. Everything you want to select from CNMSEG is already in MSEG or in MKPF.

In your case you want to select the MENGE (quantity) field from CNMSEG. As this field is in MSEG already, just select it from that table, no need to include CNMSEG:

This is your original select:

```
+ "MSEG.ZEILE,MSEG.MATNR,MAKT.MAKTX,MSEG.WERKS,MSEG.LGORT "
```

Just change it like (add MSEG-MENGE, instead of CNMSEG-MENGE):

```
+ "MSEG.ZEILE,MSEG.MATNR,MAKT.MAKTX,MSEG.WERKS,MSEG.LGORT,MSEG-MENGE "
```

No other changes are necessary.

Comment: You are right!!! I am programming in JAVA and when doing the query that you indicate me, it takes exactly 27 minutes to bring the records from MSEG, for some reason the access to the view brings me in 5 seconds the same query!!! I do not know what happens, but certain fields of the MSEG table as the amount take too long to bring it from SAP, but in any view the query takes 5 seconds, do you have any knowledge of this? if so please tell me.

Comment: Most likely for whatever reason but the DB optimizer does not find the right index for the selection. This has to be analyzed in place.

Comment: the MSEG table has 4 indexes, at the moment of making the query I give it the four indexes without any problem and it still takes me 20 minutes.

Comment: the big question is, if MATNR is any of the MSEG secondqry indexes. But as it was pointed out above the CLIENT field also has to be included into the JOIN condition between MAKT and MSEG. On the other hand the language (SPRAS) is also a key field of MAKT (material texts), so it could be an issue as well if material texts exist in several languages.